# Replace several strings using an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I need an array to make this:

```
Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}
```

Look like this before being sent:

```
Hi Manuel, you can buy chips.
```

I have tried to do this with an array like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.submitMessage', function(){

    prevContent=$('textarea').val();

    $variables = array(
        '{nom}' => 'Manuel',
        '{apl}' => 'García',
        '{var1}' => 'chips',
        '{var2}' => 'deportes y aventura',
        '{var3}' => 'informática y tecnología',
        '{cst1}' => 'Serrano, 28',
        '{cst2}' => 'Plaza del carmen, 32',
        '{cst3}' => 'García Luna, 15'
    );

    $data = prevContent;
    $data = str_replace(array_keys($variables), array_values($variables), $data);

    $.post('../actions/newMessage.php',{ms_content:$data});
```

And this is the error I get on loading the page:

[image: error]

Comment: Looks like you are using PHP functions in JavaScript? (`str_replace`, `array_keys`, `array_values`)?

Comment: you're mixing php and javascript..?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what the arrows were, I thought it was something new that I just didn't recognise, yeah this isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: You prob want a structure more like: `$variables = [{name:'{nom}', value:'Manuel'}, {name:'{apl}', value:'García'}...]`

Comment: @Liam, [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) available in new standart and in some browsers now, if before the arrow was not a string, but a variable name - it would be valid syntax for arrow func

Comment: Interesting @Grundy, first time I've seen that one, [Very, very shaky support right now though](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: @Liam anyway, error on OP: say not _arrow function - not valid syntax_, but _invalid arrow function argument_ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using PHP instead of Javascript :

You can do it as below

```
        prevContent='Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}';

        variables = {
            '{nom}' : 'Manuel',
            '{apl}' : 'García',
            '{var1}' : 'chips',
            '{var2}' : 'deportes y aventura',
            '{var3}' : 'informática y tecnología',
            '{cst1}' : 'Serrano, 28',
            '{cst2}' : 'Plaza del carmen, 32',
            '{cst3}' : 'García Luna, 15'
        };

        $.each(variables, function (key, value) {
            prevContent = prevContent.replace(key, value);
        });

        console.log(prevContent);
```

Comment: @Liam, [jquery each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) can work with object too

Comment: @Liam , try the code it will work out , and one more thing $.each is something similar to for in loop

Comment: Worked :) I'll tick in 3 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
'Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}'.replace(/(\{([^\}]+)\})/gi, function($0, $1, $2){
  return { nom: 'Manulal', var1: 'chips' }[$2] || $1;
});
```

a bit explain [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oY7hM4/1)

`/(\{([^\}]+)\})/gi`

- 1st Capturing group `(\{([^\}]+)\})`
  `\{` matches the character `{` literally

  - 2nd Capturing group `([^\}]+)`
    `[^\}]+` match a single character not present in the list below
    *Quantifier:* `+` Between `one` and `unlimited` times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
    `\}` matches the character `}` literally

  `\}` matches the character `}` literally

`g modifier`: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
`i modifier`: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: Being as you've virtually minified your code an explanation would probably be useful to the OP?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing jQuery and PHP, Do it like the below example:

```
var _str = "Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}";
var _final = _str.replace(/\{nom\}/, 'Manuel')
                .replace(/\{var1\}/, 'chips');

// _final = Hi Manuel, you can buy chips
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/zx2kfvfj/)** OR Alternative:

```
var _str = "Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}";
// Add as many value as you want to search and replace
var _replace = {'{nom}':'Manuel', '{var1}':'chips'};
var _final = '';
for( var i in _replace ) {
    var _regx = new RegExp(i, 'g');
    _final = _str.replace(_regx, _replace[i]);
}

alert(_final);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to achieve could also be done using this alternative and more generic way:

```
// input string
var inputString = "Hi {nom}, you can buy {var1}" // or $('textarea').val();

// prepare mapping object
var mappingDetails = {
    '{nom}' : 'Manuel',
    '{apl}' : 'García',
    '{var1}' : 'chips',
    '{var2}' : 'deportes y aventura',
    '{var3}' : 'informática y tecnología',
    '{cst1}' : 'Serrano, 28',
    '{cst2}' : 'Plaza del carmen, 32',
    '{cst3}' : 'García Luna, 15'
}

// get the regex
var generatedRegex = new RegExp(Object.keys(mappingDetails).join("|"),"gi");

// replace the placeholders
inputString = inputString.replace(generatedRegex , function(matchedText){
  return mappingDetails [matchedText];
});

// output
console.log(inputString);
```